# HTTPS call from HTTP page IFrame

Tags: http, iframe, https

I have got http page from where i want to make HTTPS call for login (I have already done that)

My question is :

1. Is it safe to call like this, If not what additional things we should do to support this functionality since my home page is http and when user clicks on sign in it redirects to https page, Now i want to give one drop down IFrame and ask credential and make https call from Iframe, I have seen this on some of the sites and wondering what they are doing differently for this.
2. Is there any limitation on browser that is used for this call i.e. IE Versions, Chrome, Firefox, Opera. Does it work for all browsers and versions

I have come across few old posts but could not find satisfactory answer

[HTTP and HTTPS iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144986/http-https-iframe)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My answer to the post you link to might not be "satisfactory" (it seems you want the answer to "*Is it safe to call like this?*" to be Yes anyway), but it's just the way it is: you can't expect the user to check the identity of the HTTPS site they're visiting, or even that HTTPS is used at all, if it's not the main site. This applies to iframes and AJAX calls. Unfortunately, [only the users](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628) are in a position to check that HTTPS is used and that it's used on the site they intended to contact.

Comment: Hi Bruno, Thanks for your response. I might have used wrong sentence here :)... any idea on my second point? Any documentation link would help around this if you have any.