# iframe not working in chrome browser but safari working correctly

Tags: html, security, google-chrome, iframe, content-security-policy

i'm using `iframe` for loading third party web site. not(youtube,linkedIn) it's ex: [zomato](http://www.zomato.com)
its not working in chrome .it say like this in console

```
Refused to display 'https://www.zomato.com/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the 
following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
```

but same thing is working in safari browser .

Comment: This is because Zomato is protected with a SSL certificate, and chrome won't allow you to show HTTPS content on a HTTP environment. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144986/http-https-iframe for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, zomato has a Content Security Policy which prevents being loaded in iframe of other domains.

`"frame-ancestors 'self'"` means domain of parent of zomato can only be the same as `https://www.zomato.com/`.

It works in safari because safari don't support this CSP setting yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
chromium-browser --disable-web-security
```

From the chromium source:

// Don't enforce the same-origin policy. (Used by people testing their sites.)