# Can I force click on hyperlink to open in new tab when click on link

Tags: html, href

Can I force click on hyperlink to open in new page when click on link?

My page is part of a frameset, and [links to one site has changed so it prevents the link working if comes form a frameset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383347/is-there-an-issue-opening-a-https-page-within-an-frame), but its fine if user does does cntl-click to open page in new tab.

But user doesn't know that so I want a usual click to open in new tab as well to workaround this issue.

Comment: I think its a setting users do in their browsers and you cannot force somebody if they don't have the browser-settings activated. Some people turn it off for security reasons and I don't think there is a workaround.

Comment: Have you tried `<a href="www.page.com" target="_blank">Click here</a>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open link in new tab on html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-on-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With just HTML:

```
<a href="www.targetpage.com" target="_blank"> Click here </a>
```

[Documentation on target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030283/can-i-force-click-on-hyperlink-to-open-in-new-tab-when-click-on-link/45030399#45030399)

---

You can also try with javascript (jQuery):

```
$('a.myLink').trigger(
    $.Event('click', {
        ctrlKey: true
    })
);
```

[Documentation on Event](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: Doh, yes of course, apologies for posting this question.

Answer (score 2):

```
<p> <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">click here</a></p>
```

> use target="_blank" it will open the link in new tab

Answer (score 2):

Use target="_blank" inside your link tag:

```
<a href="link" title="link title" target="_blank">link title</a>
```

See: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp